# Load format file in TeXWorks

Tags: texworks, format-files

I have a format file, let's say the file `format.fmt` that I use to initialise `luatex`.  So, if I want to process a `document.tex` I type on the command line

```
luatex -fmt format document.tex
```

I'd like to instruct TeXWorks to do the same, by creating a new processing tool under the typesetting tab in preferences.   What should I put as arguments in order to make it work?  The default arguments are `$synctexoption` and `$fullname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new tool

[image]

The trick here is to use `luahbtex` as the program, because I used `lualatex.fmt` that's created by that executable. Change the format name to the one you have and use `luatex` as the engine, if your format has been created with `luatex -ini`.

Comment: Thank you.  But why can't I use `luatex`?

Comment: @User You can use it, provided you created the format with `luatex -ini`. I added this to the answer.